# possible loss in precision for byte

Tags: java

My code is

```
class Bauua {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        byte a = 10; byte b = 20;
        byte c = a+b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

While compiling I am getting following error

```
error: possible loss of precision 
byte c= a+b;
required: byte
found:    int
```

But when I use `byte c=(byte)(a+b);` in place of `byte c = a+b;` it's compiling successfully, so my question is why I need to cast it when all the 3 variables (i.e. a, b and c) are byte data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byte c= a+b;`, the `+` operator here will return an `int` ,that's why you need to use  a cast.